# How to remove String from an array by checking length and comparing text in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, guava, apache-commons

How to remove String from an array by checking length and comparing text in Java?

Suppose user search for "Hi Tonki with Monkey"

```
String[] pattern = userSearchString.toLowerCase().split("\\s");
```

1) We want to remove "With" from pattern and

2) also want to remove pattern with less then 3 size like "Hi".

So pattern should contain Tonki and Monkey only.

It will be fuitful if anyone can suggest method from Apache Commons or Guava.

Using Java 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Java 8 solution would be to `Stream` the array and filter only the elements that you want, and collect it back into an array:

```
Arrays.stream(pattern)
      .filter(word -> !word.equals("with"))
      .filter(word -> word.length() >= 3)
      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

A pre-Java 8 solution would be to filter the array manually.  However, we'll have to create a new array; but because we do not know the size of the new array in advance, we can use a `List<String>` and collect it to an array after adding its respective elements:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (String word : pattern) {
    if (word.length() < 3 || word.equals("with")) {
        continue;
    }

    list.add(word);
}

list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

There's no need to use external libraries if they aren't required!

Comment: Thanks. It is quite easy in Java 8. I am using Java 1.6 but using Commons and Guava Library. Could you please also append solution for same.

Comment: @AxelH If you provide 0 as the length of the array, the JVM will determine the size for you.  It would be better to provide its exact size if possible, but I doubt there's any noticeable performance difference between the two.

Comment: "_what is best `list.toArray(new String[0]);` or `list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`_"Actually, just checked, the code is different if you have a correct size or not, It will use `Arrays.copyOf`... to create an `Object[]` with the correct length that will be cast after it is filled using the same logic in both case(`System.arraycopy`). Basicly, without the correct length, it would be the same to use `(T) list.toArray()` ;) but it will hide the casting

Comment: @AxelH Interesting!